# Handle OnAttach(Activity) and OnAttach(Context) on Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm developing an application that targets API 25 but supports API 17.

I'm overriding OnAttach(Activity) in this way:

```
[TargetApi(Value = 17)]
public override void OnAttach(Activity activity)
{
    base.OnAttach(activity);
    _parent = (IParent)Activity;
}
```

But I get a Warning:

> Warning CS0672: Member 'SettingsFragment.OnAttach(Activity)' overrides
>   obsolete member 'Fragment.OnAttach(Activity)'. Add the Obsolete
>   attribute to 'SettingsFragment.OnAttach(Activity)'.

Using OnAttach(Context) the app crashes on older devices.

So, what is the right to handle this warning?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnAttach (Activity activity)` was deprecated since API level 23, use `onAttach(Context)` instead.

Replace your code with :

```
public override void OnAttach(Context context)
{
    base.OnAttach(context);
    Activity a;

    if (context is Activity){
        a = (Activity)context;
    }
 }
```

Comment: The method `public override void OnAttach(Context context)` is not called on Android 4.2.
Should I keep both overrides?

Comment: Yes, in `OnAttach(Activity activity)`  you could judge the version number,<23  do what you want to do

Comment: [Obsolete("deprecation")]
    public override void OnAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        base.OnAttach(activity);
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.M)
        {
            //do something when <23
        }
    }